# Scrapy CrawlSpider crawls, but is not parsing any items

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm attempting to collect information about all of the products sold on groceries.aldi.co.uk. I have some experience scraping similar websites and have used the CrawlSpider to do so.

When I run the spider it seems to crawl throughout the website, but does not return any of the items. I've tried multiple different rule combinations as I suspect the issue is linked to these, but I haven't been able to fix it.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Here's my spider code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from aldiscraper.items import AldiscraperItem
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from datetime import datetime
import re


class AldiSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'aldi'
    start_urls = ['https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/']
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='en-GB/', deny=r'/ddddddddddddd')),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/ddddddddddddd'), callback='parse_products') 
    )
    
    custom_settings = {
            'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS': [
                'prod_id',
                'name',
                'size',
                'price',
                'scrape_date',
             ],
         }
    
    def parse_products(self, response):      
        item = AldiscraperItem()
                
        item['prod_id'] = response.css('span.sku.small::text').get()
        item['name'] = response.css('h1.my-0::text').get()
        item['size'] = response.css('span.text-black-50.font-weight-bold::text').get()   
        item['price'] = response.css('span.product-price.h4.m-0.font-weight-bold::text').get()
        item['scrape_date'] = datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
            
        yield item
```

I originally tried to run the spider using the following rules, with the same results:

```
class AldiSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'aldi'
    start_urls = ['https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/']
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='en-GB/', deny='en-GB/p-')),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='en-GB/p-'), callback='parse_products') 
    )
```

I'm using this command to run the spider:

```
scrapy crawl aldi -O aldi.csv
```

And here's an extract from the logs

```
2022-04-11 19:32:04 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.6.1 started (bot: aldi)
2022-04-11 19:32:04 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.6.3.0, libxml2 2.9.12, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 22.2.0, Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 16:59:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 21.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021), cryptography 3.4.8, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19044-SP0
2022-04-11 19:32:04 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'aldi',
 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False,
 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0.75,
 'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS': ['prod_id', 'name', 'size', 'price', 'scrape_date'],
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'aldiscraper.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['aldiscraper.spiders']}
2022-04-11 19:32:04 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2022-04-11 19:32:04 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 2072eb077b8dcc04
2022-04-11 19:32:05 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2022-04-11 19:32:06 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2022-04-11 19:32:06 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2022-04-11 19:32:06 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2022-04-11 19:32:06 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-04-11 19:32:06 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-04-11 19:32:06 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2022-04-11 19:32:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2022-04-11 19:32:07 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/> from <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/>
2022-04-11 19:32:09 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/> (referer: None)
2022-04-11 19:32:09 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/#footer-collapse-0> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2022-04-11 19:32:10 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/forgot-password> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/)
2022-04-11 19:32:12 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/bakery/bread?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=bakery&c3=bread&c4=sliced-bread&clickedon=sliced-bread> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/)
2022-04-11 19:32:13 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/bakery?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=bakery&c3=bread&c4=shopall-bread&clickedon=shopall-bread> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/)
2022-04-11 19:32:13 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/bakery/bread?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=bakery&c3=bread&clickedon=bread> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/)
2022-04-11 19:32:14 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/bakery?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=bakery&c3=shopall-bakery&clickedon=shopall-bakery> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/)
2022-04-11 19:32:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/bakery?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=bakery&clickedon=bakery> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/)
2022-04-11 19:32:16 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range/vegan-drinks/vegan-alcohol?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=vegan-plant-based&c3=vegan-drinks&c4=vegan-alcohol&clickedon=vegan-alcohol> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/)
2022-04-11 19:32:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range/vegan-drinks/milk-alternatives?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=vegan-plant-based&c3=vegan-drinks&c4=milk-alternatives&clickedon=milk-alternatives> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/)
2022-04-11 19:32:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range/vegan-drinks?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=vegan-plant-based&c3=vegan-drinks&c4=shopall-vegan-drinks&clickedon=shopall-vegan-drinks> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/)
2022-04-11 19:32:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range/vegan-drinks?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=vegan-plant-based&c3=vegan-drinks&clickedon=vegan-drinks> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/)
2022-04-11 19:32:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range/vegan-food/vegan-sides-snacks?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=vegan-plant-based&c3=vegan-food&c4=vegan-sides-snacks&clickedon=vegan-sides-snacks> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/)
2022-04-11 19:32:21 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range/vegan-food/vegan-meat-alternatives?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=vegan-plant-based&c3=vegan-food&c4=meat-alternatives&clickedon=meat-alternatives> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/)
2022-04-11 19:32:22 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range/vegan-food?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=vegan-plant-based&c3=vegan-food&c4=shopall-vegan-food&clickedon=shopall-vegan-food> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/)
2022-04-11 19:32:23 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range/vegan-food?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=vegan-plant-based&c3=vegan-food&clickedon=vegan-food> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/)
2022-04-11 19:32:24 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=vegan-plant-based&c3=shopall-vegan-plant-based&clickedon=shopall-vegan-plant-based> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/)
2022-04-11 19:32:25 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=vegan-plant-based&clickedon=vegan-plant-based> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/)
2022-04-11 19:32:25 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/Grocery-Click-and-Collect/Notify-Me> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/)
2022-04-11 19:32:26 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/Modern-Slavery-Act?origin=footer&c1=about-aldi&c2=modern-slavery-act&clickedon=modern-slavery-act> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/)
2022-04-11 19:32:27 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/bakery/bread?sortDirection=asc&page=3> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/bakery/bread?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=bakery&c3=bread&c4=sliced-bread&clickedon=sliced-bread)
2022-04-11 19:32:28 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/bakery?sortDirection=asc&page=7> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/bakery?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=bakery&c3=bread&c4=shopall-bread&clickedon=shopall-bread)
2022-04-11 19:32:31 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/bakery?sortDirection=asc&page=6> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/bakery?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=bakery&c3=bread&c4=shopall-bread&clickedon=shopall-bread)
2022-04-11 19:32:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/bakery?sortDirection=asc&page=5> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/bakery?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=bakery&c3=bread&c4=shopall-bread&clickedon=shopall-bread)
2022-04-11 19:32:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/bakery?sortDirection=asc&page=4> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/bakery?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=bakery&c3=bread&c4=shopall-bread&clickedon=shopall-bread)
2022-04-11 19:32:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range/vegan-drinks/vegan-alcohol?sortDirection=asc&page=1> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range/vegan-drinks/vegan-alcohol?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=vegan-plant-based&c3=vegan-drinks&c4=vegan-alcohol&clickedon=vegan-alcohol)
2022-04-11 19:32:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range/vegan-drinks/milk-alternatives?sortDirection=asc&page=1> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range/vegan-drinks/milk-alternatives?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=vegan-plant-based&c3=vegan-drinks&c4=milk-alternatives&clickedon=milk-alternatives)
2022-04-11 19:33:00 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range/vegan-drinks> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range/vegan-drinks/vegan-alcohol?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=vegan-plant-based&c3=vegan-drinks&c4=vegan-alcohol&clickedon=vegan-alcohol)
2022-04-11 19:33:01 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range/vegan-drinks?sortDirection=asc&page=1> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range/vegan-drinks?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=vegan-plant-based&c3=vegan-drinks&c4=shopall-vegan-drinks&clickedon=shopall-vegan-drinks)
2022-04-11 19:33:01 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range/vegan-food/vegan-sides-snacks?sortDirection=asc&page=1> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range/vegan-food/vegan-sides-snacks?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=vegan-plant-based&c3=vegan-food&c4=vegan-sides-snacks&clickedon=vegan-sides-snacks)
2022-04-11 19:33:02 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range/vegan-food/vegan-meat-alternatives?sortDirection=asc&page=1> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range/vegan-food/vegan-meat-alternatives?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=vegan-plant-based&c3=vegan-food&c4=meat-alternatives&clickedon=meat-alternatives)
2022-04-11 19:33:03 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range/vegan-food?sortDirection=asc&page=1> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range/vegan-food?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=vegan-plant-based&c3=vegan-food&c4=shopall-vegan-food&clickedon=shopall-vegan-food)
2022-04-11 19:33:04 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range/vegan-food> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range/vegan-food/vegan-sides-snacks?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=vegan-plant-based&c3=vegan-food&c4=vegan-sides-snacks&clickedon=vegan-sides-snacks)
2022-04-11 19:33:05 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range?sortDirection=asc&page=3> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=vegan-plant-based&c3=shopall-vegan-plant-based&clickedon=shopall-vegan-plant-based)
2022-04-11 19:33:06 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range?sortDirection=asc&page=2> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=vegan-plant-based&c3=shopall-vegan-plant-based&clickedon=shopall-vegan-plant-based)
2022-04-11 19:33:06 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/Grocery-Click-and-Collect> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/Grocery-Click-and-Collect/Notify-Me)
2022-04-11 19:33:06 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 36 pages (at 36 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-04-11 19:33:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/Login> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/Grocery-Click-and-Collect/Notify-Me)
2022-04-11 19:33:09 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range?sortDirection=asc&page=1> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=vegan-plant-based&c3=shopall-vegan-plant-based&clickedon=shopall-vegan-plant-based)
2022-04-11 19:33:11 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range/vegan-drinks/vegan-alcohol?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=vegan-plant-based&c3=vegan-drinks&c4=vegan-alcohol&clickedon=vegan-alcohol)
2022-04-11 19:33:11 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/bakery?sortDirection=asc&page=3> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/bakery?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=bakery&c3=bread&c4=shopall-bread&clickedon=shopall-bread)
2022-04-11 19:33:13 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/bakery?sortDirection=asc&page=2> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/bakery?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=bakery&c3=bread&c4=shopall-bread&clickedon=shopall-bread)
2022-04-11 19:33:14 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/bakery?sortDirection=asc&page=1> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/bakery?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=bakery&c3=bread&c4=shopall-bread&clickedon=shopall-bread)
2022-04-11 19:33:14 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/easter/hot-cross-buns> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/bakery?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=bakery&c3=bread&c4=shopall-bread&clickedon=shopall-bread)
2022-04-11 19:33:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/bakery/bread?sortDirection=asc&page=2> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/bakery/bread?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=bakery&c3=bread&c4=sliced-bread&clickedon=sliced-bread)
2022-04-11 19:33:16 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/About-Click--Collect?origin=footer&c1=about-aldi&c2=covid-19&clickedon=covid-19> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/)
2022-04-11 19:33:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/bakery/bread?sortDirection=asc&page=1> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/bakery/bread?origin=dropdown&c1=groceries&c2=bakery&c3=bread&c4=sliced-bread&clickedon=sliced-bread)
2022-04-11 19:33:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/Privacy-Notice?origin=footer&c1=help&c2=privacy-notice&clickedon=privacy-notice> (referer: https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/)
```

And finally, here are the stats:

```
2022-04-11 19:49:55 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-04-11 19:49:55 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 5,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/scrapy.exceptions.IgnoreRequest': 5,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 539252,
 'downloader/request_count': 1095,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1095,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 56319721,
 'downloader/response_count': 1095,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1087,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 4,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 455167,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 1068.912414,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 11, 18, 49, 55, 791572),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 370815991,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 1091,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1102,
 'log_count/INFO': 27,
 'request_depth_max': 4,
 'response_received_count': 1091,
 'robotstxt/forbidden': 5,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1099,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1099,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1099,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1099,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 11, 18, 32, 6, 879158)}
2022-04-11 19:49:55 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

The only other output is a completely blank CSV file.

I can't understand why it is scraping the pages but not returning any items. Thanks in advance for any help you can give me!

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url is dynamically populated by javascript and `crawlspider` can't render javascript meaning `scrapy` can't render javascript. So you have to use an automation tool something like selenium with scrapy a bit complex or You can easily grab data from api  if they exist hidden api. Here is an example how to extract data from api as the url contains api.

```
import scrapy
import json
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class AldiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'aldi'
    
    def start_requests(self):
        api_url='https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/api/aldisearchquery/productset?productSetName=Easter'
        headers= {
            "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
            "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36",
            }
        yield scrapy.Request (
            url=api_url,
            method="GET",
            headers=headers,
            callback=self.parse
            )
    def parse(self,response):
        resp=json.loads(response.body)
       
        for item in resp:
            yield {
                'DisplayName':item.get('DisplayName')}
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(AldiSpider)
    process.start()
```

Output:

```
{'DisplayName': 'Dairyfine Sparkle The Unicorn Milk Chocolate Egg & Toy 100g'}
2022-04-12 03:56:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/api/aldisearchquery/productset?productSetName=Easter>
{'DisplayName': 'Dairyfine Bumper Egg Hunt Pack 700g'}
2022-04-12 03:56:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/api/aldisearchquery/productset?productSetName=Easter>
{'DisplayName': 'Moser Roth Belgian Milk & White Chocolate Caramel Egg Slab 120g'}        
2022-04-12 03:56:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/api/aldisearchquery/productset?productSetName=Easter>
{'DisplayName': 'Moser Roth Belgian Dark Chocolate & Raspberry Egg Slab 120g'}
2022-04-12 03:56:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/api/aldisearchquery/productset?productSetName=Easter>
{'DisplayName': 'Dairyfine Giant Milk Chocolate Bunny 300g'}
2022-04-12 03:56:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/api/aldisearchquery/productset?productSetName=Easter>
{'DisplayName': 'Kit Kat Chunky Milk Chocolate Large Easter Egg 230g'}
2022-04-12 03:56:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/api/aldisearchquery/productset?productSetName=Easter>
{'DisplayName': 'Dairyfine Milk Chocolate Bunnies 125g'}
2022-04-12 03:56:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/api/aldisearchquery/productset?productSetName=Easter>
{'DisplayName': 'Moser Roth Milk Chocolate Truffle Luxury Filled Eggs 150g'}
2022-04-12 03:56:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/api/aldisearchquery/productset?productSetName=Easter>
{'DisplayName': 'Dairyfine Mini Mix Ups 212g'}
2022-04-12 03:56:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/api/aldisearchquery/productset?productSetName=Easter>
{'DisplayName': 'Dairyfine Eggjoyables Cookies & Cream 144g'}
2022-04-12 03:56:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/api/aldisearchquery/productset?productSetName=Easter>
{'DisplayName': 'Dairyfine White Hot Chocolate Melting Unicorn 65g'}
2022-04-12 03:56:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/api/aldisearchquery/productset?productSetName=Easter>
{'DisplayName': 'Dairyfine Milk Hot Chocolate Melting Chick 65g'}
2022-04-12 03:56:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/api/aldisearchquery/productset?productSetName=Easter>
{'DisplayName': 'Dairyfine Milk Chocolate Bunny 125g'}
2022-04-12 03:56:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/api/aldisearchquery/productset?productSetName=Easter>
{'DisplayName': 'Dairyfine Milk Chocolate Easter Bunny Lollies 10 Pack'}
2022-04-12 03:56:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/api/aldisearchquery/productset?productSetName=Easter>
{'DisplayName': 'Dairyfine Milk Chocolate Eggs 100g'}
2022-04-12 03:56:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/api/aldisearchquery/productset?productSetName=Easter>
{'DisplayName': 'Maltesers Chocolate Mini Bunnies Bag 58g'}
2022-04-12 03:56:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/api/aldisearchquery/productset?productSetName=Easter>
{'DisplayName': 'Dairyfine Mini Chocolate Eggs 80g'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have been able to replicate your results and scrape the names of those Easter products. I haven't been able to find a way of replicating this with the rest of the range and other information such as price, but that's not related to my original question, so thanks!